# (taylor series) For what range of $x$ can $\sin x=x$ approximation be used to relative accuracy of $\frac{1}{2}10^{-14}$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

For what range of $x$ can $\sin x=x$ approximation be used to a relative accuracy of $\frac{1}{2}10^{-14}$?

The taylor series for $\sin x$ is 
$$
x-\frac1{3!}x^3+\frac1{5!}x^5-\frac1{7!}x^7+\dots
$$ 
So the absolute value of $\frac1{3!}x^3+\frac1{5!}x^5-\frac1{7!}x^7+\dots$ has to be smaller than $\frac{1}{2}10^{-14}$. I don't know where to go from here. Thanks for the help.

Comment: You just need to consider the first term, namely the $-\frac{x^3}{3!}$. The rest are of higher order. You may also take a look at the form of Taylor expansion with a residue term.

Answer (score 2):

The error in an alternating series is only as large as the first term not in the truncation, i.e. here
$$
\left|\frac{x^3}{6}\right|
$$
you will be expanding on a symmetric interval around $0$ of the form $(-a,a)$, so you need 
$$
\left|a^3\right|\leq6\frac{1}{2}10^{-14}=3(10^{-14})\implies |a|\leq\sqrt[3]{3}10^{-14/3}
$$

Edit: As noted, perhaps it would be easier to tell how big this is by writing
$$
\sqrt[3]{3}10^{-14/3}=\sqrt[3]{30\cdot10^{-15}}=\sqrt[3]{30}\left(10^{-5}\right )
$$

Comment: Perhaps write the bound as $\sqrt[3]{30}\,10^{-5}$ or $3\sqrt[3]{1+\frac19}\,10^{-5}$ to get an easier appreciation of its numerical value.

Comment: @LutzL fair point, I will edit the above